# Can you have an object within an object?

Tags: java

int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

int array2[] = {array1, 2,3,4,5};

Now, I want to access the 1st element of array1 within array2.

int temp = array2[0].[0];

What's wrong with this?

Comment: `int[]` is not the same thing as `int`. An array of ints (`int[]`) can only contain ints, and *not* other arrays of ints. You cannot have a `int[]` inside another `int[]`.

Comment: @Gendarme It was a typo. I meant to say "int array1[]". Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Also, I see what you're saying. That solves my confusion. Thank you!

Comment: Your `array2` contains `array1` which is not possible, since they are both arrays of ints. An array of ints can only contains ints, not other arrays of ints.

Answer (score 3):

While this will work:

```
public class ObjectArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Object[] array2 = {array1, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println(((Object[])array2[0])[0]);
    }

}
```

It's a terrible idea... Basically to accomplish what you need you have to use the base Object type since you're mixing types without any kind of inheritance. And you have to cast the Objects to their appropriate type to make them usable.

Comment: I was thinking about implementing multi-valued variables to sync in with single valued ones.

For Example: Name, Address, DOB.
Name would be a set of values, i.e. First _name & Last_Name.

So, 
My 'String [] Info' would contain:

Info[0] = Name;
Info[1] = Address; 
Info[2] = DOB;

But then, my Name would have have:
Name[0] = First_Name;
Name[1] = Last_Name;

Now, the real question is:
How do I access Last_Name of the Nth record in 'Info[N]'?

Comment: @EricFernandes this is still a terrible idea.  You should have a class with `name`, `address`, and `dateOfBirth` fields instead of shoving all this into arrays.

Answer (score 0):

@EricFernandes  When you define an integer array

```
int []a=new int[1];
```

you are telling the compiler that your array consists of integer type elements although you can always type cast them to object type but still if you want to use the functionality that you are saying ,it is possible; although a cleaner and better version would be using arraylist of arraylists(in that way you would be able to implement your idea as well as dynamic array).

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3);
a.add(4);
a.add(5);
al.add(a);
al.add((new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(1));
al.add((new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(2));
al.add((new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(3));
al.add((new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(4));
al.add((new ArrayList<Integer>()).add(5));
Iterator it=al.iterator();
System.out.println(al.get(0).get(0));
```